# Using awk to print

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I currently have a script that will query the ownership of the partition.dumodule and have it print out the information:

```
 echo *Checking Partition Permission* Hostname=$(hostname) LastChecked=$(date)
 ls -l /applications/utilities/Disk\ Utility.app/contents/Plugins | grep Partition.dumodule | awk -v a=Username= -v b=DateModified= '{print a $3, b $6, $7, $8}'
```

It will print out like this:

```
 *Checking Partition Permission* Hostname=<name> LastChecked=<date> 
 Username=<account> DateModified=<date>
```

Notice how the " Username= DateModified=" is on a separate line, this is the issue. I need it to all appear on the same line but I cannot figure out how to do this. I believe what needs to be done is have awk print out everything instead of running the "Hostname=$(hostname) LastChecked=$(date)" in the beginning, but how do I get awk to print out that information? 
I have seen some forums and people say you can do something like this:

```
 awk -v MYHOST=$(hostname) '{print MYHOST " " $4}'
```

However that gives me an error if you put the "MYHOST" variable to be printed. Any ideas?

Comment: That last statement will only produce an error on old, broken awk. If you are on Solaris, use nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. If that's not the issue, post the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your echo statement is emitting a newline after it.  Use `-n` to suppress the newline.

```
echo -n *Checking Partition Permission* Hostname=$(hostname) LastChecked=$(date)
```